# How can I adjust distance between equation

Tags: equations, positioning

I'm having a lateX course. We are required to generate some pdfs of a  book with lateX. In my homework, there are some math equations and notes. I find I can't adjust the distance of two equations perfectly. Here is my lateX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
8000 &=10,000 e^{k(1)}  \hspace*{11pt} \color{cyan}\begin{array}{l}
\text {Eq. }(\ref{eq5-en}) \text { with } t=1 \text { and } \\
{\small y=8000}
\end{array} \\
e^{k} &=0.8  \\
\ln (e^{k}) &=\ln 0.8 \hspace*{40pt} \color{cyan}\text{Logs of both sides}\\
k &=\ln 0.8<0. \hspace*{22pt} \color{cyan}\text{$\ln 0.8 \approx -0.223$}
\end{aligned} 
\]

\end{document}
```

and I got this:
[image: ![![enter image description here]

instead of
[image]

It seems there are some problems in the distance between 1st equation and 2nd equation. I also tried to add `[-8pt]` to `\end{array} \\ e^{k} &=0.8  \\` which becomes `\end{array} \\[-8pt] e^{k} &=0.8  \\` and I got this:
[image: ![![enter image description here]

As you can see, the 1st equation doesm't match the notes horizontally. How can I fix this problem to achieve things shown in graph-2(image behind 'instead of')?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should use the `[t]` optional argument of the array environment.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. For uninitiated like me, there are so many new things I've never heard.

Comment: Onz shiuld always look at the packages documentations, you know. You'll also learn from this site.

Comment: Ok. Actually, I solve many problems previously with the helo of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you (a) use an `align*` environment instead of a combination of `\[ ... \]` and an `aligned` environment, (b) use the fact that one can have more than one alignment point per row, and (c) place the explanatory material for the first row in a `\smash[b]{\parbox[t]{...}{...}}` construct. (Using an `array` environment for item (c) seems like a rather tedious way to go.)

Incidentally, you should also replace `10,000` with `10{,}000`, to keep TeX from treating the `,` symbol as a punctuation marker.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman fonts
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
8000 &= 10{,}000 e^{k(1)}  && 
        \color{cyan}\smash[b]{\parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
        \raggedright Eq.\ \eqref{eq5-en} with  $t=1$ and $y=8000$.}} \\
e^{k} &= 0.8  \\
\ln e^{k} &= \ln 0.8 && 
        \color{cyan}\text{Logs of both sides} \\
k &= \ln 0.8<0. &&
        \color{cyan}{\ln 0.8 \approx -0.223}
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I think I still need some fine tuning. Sincerely hope  you can give me answers or hints if I have new problem.